# get untitled column data from CSV file

Tags: java

I have this code, which supposed to retrieve data from CSV file, the file (set of files) structure is as following: [Mary, 7, 17] but the columns are not titled, so I only got A, B, C
when I run the code I seem to have only the first result in the column.
can anybody help me to iterate throw all records?

```
public void searchFiles()
    {        
        int count = 0;
        DirectoryResource c = new DirectoryResource();
        int summ = 0;
        int currentrow = 0;
        String name = "ff";
        String k = "Susan";
        for(File f : c.selectedFiles())
        {
            FileResource fr = new FileResource(f);
            CSVParser currentFile = fr.getCSVParser(false);
            currentrow = 0;
            for (CSVRecord row : currentFile)
            {
                currentrow++;
                name = row.get(0);
                if(row.get(0) == k)
                {
                    count++;
                    summ = summ + currentrow;
                    System.out.println("Row is : " + row.getRecordNumber() + " / " + currentrow);
                    break;
                }
                else
                {                    
                    System.out.println("found");
                }
            }            
            System.out.println(count + " / " + currentrow + " / " + name);
        }        
        System.out.println("count is: " + count);
        System.out.println("Summ is: " + summ);
        System.out.println("Avg is: " + (summ / count));
    }
```

Answer (score -2):

I should use .equals() insted of == in the if statement

```
if(row.get(0).equals(k))
```